# How to define nested dictionary type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to define a type for an object with a *nested* structure like this:

```
const nestedDictionary = {
   a: {
     b: true
   },
   c: true,
   d: {
     e: {
       f: true
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```ts
type Dictionary = {
  [x: string]: boolean | Dictionary;
};

const nestedDictionary: Dictionary;
```

Or, if you prefer to use type as a parameter:

```ts
type GenericDictionary<T> = {
  [x: string]: T | GenericDictionary<T>;
};

const nestedDictionary: GenericDictionary<boolean>;
```